# Route traffic from firewall tunnel interface to server in Azure

Tags: vpn, firewall, azure

On premise is a NAS that users access for file storage. Their AD server for authentication and GPO is in Azure.

For remote users, they have a Remote Access VPN client in which they connect to the firewall on the network edge. Remote users wish to login to the VPN client and access files on the NAS.

The firewall is a Sophos XGS116 and is configured to authenticate the VPN users with the Active Directory server.

Per the configuration file downloaded from Azure from the Azure Connection, the IP address for the tunnel interface as configured in the firewall is to be assigned the address of 169.254.0.1/32.

Firewall "System Generated" traffic to the AD server hosted in Azure does not pass as it is sourced from the egress interface with the LINK-LOCAL (or APIPA) address above.

I added inbound and outbound rules in Azure to the Network Security Group to allow traffic to/from that IP. I've added the 169.254.0.1/32 subnet to the Azure Local Network Gateway. However, traffic does not pass from the firewall to the server.

When running a packet capture on the firewall, I do see the traffic sourced from the firewall's tunnel interface IP out the correct interface.

Is there some routing somewhere in Azure that can be modified to allow this traffic?

Edit - Clarity of the question.

Comment: Packets with addresses in the Link-Local `169.254.0.0/16` range cannot be routed. The RFC clearly explains: "_The host MUST NOT send a packet with an IPv4 Link-Local destination address to any router for forwarding._" Also, "_A router MUST NOT forward a packet with an IPv4 Link-Local source or destination address, irrespective of the router's default route configuration or routes obtained from dynamic routing protocols._"

Comment: Please provide the documentation that indicates you should use an Link Local/APIPA address for a VPN tunnel interface. That seems very incorrect to me and documentation I found for VPN tunnel to Azure VPN gateway instances does not say to do that. Providing detail on the firewall in use would be helpful as well.

Comment: Firewall in use is Sophos XGS.

The configuration file downloaded from Microsoft for the Azure Connection has the APIPA IP address embedded.  There is no way to change this IP address assignment from Microsoft.

Comment: I previously configured fortigate-azure vpn and saw the same thing. Azure uses APIPA ip for tunnel ip address so tunnel ip addresses do not interfere with an ip address that can potentially be used later on. here is a guide for sophos https://community.sophos.com/sophos-xg-firewall/f/recommended-reads/118402/sophos-xg-firewall-v17-x-how-to-establish-a-site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-to-microsoft-azure

Comment: Thanks @kaya atabey.  That link is for building a site-to-site policy based VPN instead of a route-based VPN. Things have changed quite a bit since SFOS v17 and now route based VPNs are the norm in Sophos as well as Azure and AWS. As we have a route-based VPN in place and I wanted to continue to use it as they are a bit more efficient in terms of the ability to manipulate while remaining up and consume fewer resources on the firewalls.

Comment: I've edited this for clarity twice now and someone refuses to open the question back up.  There is no information in the notice I received about what further information I can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

A senior support engineer from Sophos got back to me with this:

Overview
This article describes the steps to translate the generated traffic by the firewall via network address translation (NAT) so that the IP address of its interfaces are not exposed or change the NAT'd IP for traffic going to a destination.

Product and Environment
Sophos Firewall - All supported versions

Translating the generated traffic via NAT
Go to the command line of your firewall.
Select Option 4. Device Console.
Run the following command:

Syntax:

```
set advanced-firewall sys-traffic-nat add destination <destination IP address> snatip <SNAT IP address>
```

Example:

```
set advanced-firewall sys-traffic-nat add destination 10.0.0.4 snatip 192.168.1.1
```

This worked for my situation.  Now traffic to the AD server hosted in Azure sourced from the firewall for user authentication comes from the LAN interface IP of 192.168.1.1 instead of the tunnel interface IP of 169.254.0.1. However it's harder for lower level technicians as they cannot simply "see" this in the GUI.  Additionally, I don't know if the CLI solution is backed up in the event the firewall needs to be replaced.

Source Article:
https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000035607?language=en_US

**SOLUTION 2**

I also spoke with a Microsoft engineer a few weeks later.

The engineer told me that the IP address assigned to the tunnel interface in the on-premise firewall doesn't matter.  Although the configuration file downloaded from Microsoft for a generic router specifies the interface IP as 169.254.0.1/32,it can be any RFC1918 address.

In Azure:
I added 192.168.219.1/32 in the inbound allow rules in the Network Security Group for the server I wanted to reach.
I added this as a subnet in the Local Network Gateway.

In the firewall:
I disabled the Sophos provided solution.

```
set advanced-firewall sys-traffic-nat delete destination 10.0.0.4 snatip 192.168.1.1
```

I changed the IP on the tunnel interface from 169.254.0.1 to 192.168.219.1.

Now the firewall can directly talk to the Active Directory server and authenticate users as they login to the firewall's user portal/VPN client.

*edit - Clarity, add Microsoft solution.